# Accessing a Module Resource with Rails 4.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I am using rails 4.1 with Casein CMS: https://github.com/russellquinn/casein

I have setup a Post Model, view and controllers within casein, but I would like to access the Posts outside of casein, possibly under another route called *blog*

I have tried and tried reworking my routes and controllers, and have an array of errors to list. Someone here might know just the trick to get this working, and was hoping some could help me, or at least explain to me what should be happening or what I might be doing wrong.

What Casein adds to the routes is this:

```
#Casein routes
 namespace :casein do
    resources :posts
end
```

And I'd like to match the index and show actions to => /blog. How might I write this correctly in my routes.rb.

My controller, I have basically extracted the actions from the Casein's PostsController, and along with including the Casein Module have tried to simple list all the posts.

Here is what my blogs_controller's index action looks like:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
module Casein
  def index
      @casein_page_title = 'Posts'
        @posts = Post.order(sort_order(:title)).paginate :page => params[:page]
    end

  end
end
```

By the end I'd also like to take blogs to blog, but I think  can take it from there, but if anyone has any suggestions, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: On Your blogs controller, shouldn't the module contain the class and not vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be asking for this, but your question is not very clear.

If you want to have the following routes and use the same controller for each.

```
          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                      Controller#Action
    casein_posts GET    /casein/posts(.:format)          casein/posts#index
                 POST   /casein/posts(.:format)          casein/posts#create
 new_casein_post GET    /casein/posts/new(.:format)      casein/posts#new
edit_casein_post GET    /casein/posts/:id/edit(.:format) casein/posts#edit
     casein_post GET    /casein/posts/:id(.:format)      casein/posts#show
                 PATCH  /casein/posts/:id(.:format)      casein/posts#update
                 PUT    /casein/posts/:id(.:format)      casein/posts#update
                 DELETE /casein/posts/:id(.:format)      casein/posts#destroy
            blog GET    /blog(.:format)                  casein/posts#index
                 GET    /blog/:id(.:format)              casein/posts#show
```

then your config/routes.rb file should contain

```
namespace :casein do
  resources :posts
end
get '/blog', to: 'casein/posts#index'
get '/blog/:id', to: 'casein/posts#show'
```

And you need your controller to be app/controllers/casein/posts_controller.rb

But I'd really strongly encourage you to use 2 different controllers, and a concern for the shared methods

Comment: That did get me the resources I wanted, but I guess I was hoping for just the content. I'll try and figure it from here. Thank you

Comment: If you want just the content you could use a different controller for the blog than for the casein/posts.  Both can use the same model with no issues